# Change the title of window.open

Tags: javascript

I have a window.open function call on click, which opens an .swf albumplayer.

```
var win = null;
function NewWindow(wizpage, wizname, w, h, scroll){
LeftPosition = (screen.width) ? (screen.width-w)-8 : 0;
TopPosition = (screen.height) ? (screen.height-h)/2 : 0;
settings = 'height=' + h + ',width=' + w + ',top= 100,' + TopPosition + ',left=' + LeftPosition + ',scrollbars=' + scroll + ',resizable';
win = window.open(wizpage, wizname, settings);
}
```

I would want to change the title of the opened window, that it has some meaningful title (a constant 'Album Player' or something would be fine), so that doesn't use the default filename/application-shockwave... text.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 10):

Then put it to onload event:

```
win.onload = function() { this.document.title = "your new title"; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var win = null;
function NewWindow(wizpage, wizname, w, h, scroll){
  LeftPosition = (screen.width) ? (screen.width-w)-8 : 0;
  TopPosition = (screen.height) ? (screen.height-h)/2 : 0;
  settings = 'height=' + h + ',width=' + w + ',top= 100,' + TopPosition + ',left=' + LeftPosition + ',scrollbars=' + scroll + ',resizable';
  win = window.open(wizpage, wizname, settings);
  win.document.title = "your new title";
}
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it doesn't work well, for a moment the title appears, but then it is rewritten with the swf name as before. :-( eg. http://mind-jart.baksagaspar.com/mindkiller/ben-garbo/  (bottom, albumplayer)

Answer (score 0):

```
 function fnDurationPrint(displayText, dateText) {
             var WindowObject = window.open('', "DurationText", "width=430,height=250,top=200,left=250,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=no");
             WindowObject.document.writeln("<li>" + displayText + "</li>");
             WindowObject.document.title = "Duration Text of " + dateText;
         }
```

//WindowObject.document.title = must always be last after all code in javascript function